# Python - NameError name [variable] is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.3

### Original question for context:

---

I was working on a quick little password program and came across the error:
NameError name 'confirm' is not defined.
I am using Python 3.3, I am trying to use a password then enter no (2) it then supplys me with the error.
Here is my code:

```
password=input ("Enter a password: ")
print ('Are you sure ' +password+ ' is a safe password?')
print ("1. YES")
print ("2. NO")
confirm=input ("Insert a number: ")

if comfirm is 2:
  password=input ("Enter a password: ")
  print ('Are you sure ' +password+ ' is a safe password?')
  print ("1. YES")
  print ("2. NO")
  confirm=input ("Insert a number: ")

  if confirm is 2:
    password=input ("Enter a password: ")
    print ('Are you sure ' +password+ ' is a safe password?')
    print ("1. YES")
    print ("2. NO")
    confirm=input ("Insert a number: ")
```

---

### Edit, a few years later:

Please ensure you always look over your code for spelling and syntaxical mistakes, especially in new lines of code you have just deployed/built/executed. Mistakes can range from spelling mistakes to incorrect case or to syntax and beyond.

Comment: I am guessing its in the first `if` , you are using `comfirm` (notice the `m`) instead of `confirm` .

Comment: Its a typo just with spelling `confirm` in your first if statement.

Comment: Thank you both, this worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a typo error-if **comfirm** is 2: